# Grid View and media player on Click

Tags: android, gridview

How can I set my code to click on 1st item in Grid View?
I got this `

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snd1);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            mp.start();

        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            break;
        case 1:
                             break;

              }

    }
});   `
```

I got this code, but it's playing the sound on every item in the Grid View.
How can I set it so it clicks only on 1st? Or 2nd Or 3d?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Change to this:

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snd1);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            mp.start();  // This will make  sound
            break;
        case 1:
            mp2.start(); // This will make different sound
            break;


              }

    }
});
```

Comment: Yea this is working as said below, 1 more thing, how to set for 2nd? Mp2 on second item.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you have to put your `mp.start();` to the switch? Like that:

```
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snd1);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {        

        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            mp.start();
        case 1:
                             break;

              }

    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah now it's playing only on 1st Item, How to set another Mp to play on 2nd item? I am kinda new in programming. I appreciate your help

Comment: Create a second MediaPlayer (eg. mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.otherfile) ) object and add it to case 1.